# Updating table fields on submit button

Tags: php, laravel, controller, sql-update, laravel-4.2

I am very much new to laravel framework. 
I have one form , which i need to update on submit button click. 
when submit button clicks control goes to controller.php 's update() function . 
But I am unable to edit any field's value.

here is my code.

```
    public function update($id)
    {
        //echo "<pre>";print_r(Input::all());exit;

        $product    = $this->product->find($id);

        $input      = Input::only('designer', 'sku', 'name', 'display_name', 'description', 'price', 'main_category', 'sub_category', 'lead_time', 'sizing', 'woven', 'body_fabric', 'lining_fabric', 'fit', 'primary_color', 'secondary_color', 'care_label', 'neck_type', 'closure', 'trims', 'special_finishings', 'image1', 'image2', 'image3', 'image4', 'image5','top', 'combo_products', 'keywords', 'visibility', 'featured');
        //echo "<pre>";print_r($input);exit;

        try
        {
            $this->adminNewProductForm->validate($input);


        } catch(\Laracasts\Validation\FormValidationException $e)
        {
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($e->getErrors());


        }

        $slug       = Str::slug(Input::get('name'));

        $slug       = $this->product->getSlug($slug);

        $input      = array_add($input, 'slug', $slug);


        DB::transaction(function() use($product, $input)
        {

            $product->fill($input)->save();

            $stock_count    = 0;

            if(!empty(Input::get('xsmall_size')))
            {
                $rows = DB::table('products_variants')->where('product_id', $product->id)->where('variant_name', 'XS')->get();

                $stock_count += Input::get('xsmall_stock');

                if(!empty($rows))
                {
                    DB::table('products_variants')->where('product_id', $product->id)->where('variant_name', 'XS')->update(array('variant_specs' => Input::get('xsmall_size'), 'price_change' => Input::get('xsmall_price'), 'total_stock' => Input::get('xsmall_stock'), 'stock_used' => 0));


                } else {

                    DB::table('products_variants')->insert(array('product_id' => $product->id, 'variant_name' => 'XS', 'variant_specs' => Input::get('xsmall_size'), 'price_change' => Input::get('xsmall_price'), 'total_stock' => Input::get('xsmall_stock'), 'stock_used' => 0));

                }

            }

$input = array();

            $input['flagship_status'] = Input::get('flagship_status');

            if(Input::get('flagship_status'))
            {

                $input['stock_count'] = Input::get('small_stock');

            }else {

                $input['stock_count'] = $stock_count;
            }

            $product->fill($input)->save();

        });

        //echo "<pre>";print_r(Input::all());exit;

        return Redirect::back()->withFlashMessage('Product Updated Successfully!');

    }
```

Also I cant understand  , what is going on by this line ? because i did not find validate function anywhere in my code.

```
$this->adminNewProductForm->validate($input);
```

I need to update table **products** not **products_variants**.

Answer (score 0):

`validate` is inherited from the `FormRequst` class.

https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.html#method_validate

You've provided too much code and too little information. You said you need to update a specific table, but yet there are two lines where you are very intentionally manually updating a database entry.

This is one of them:

```
DB::table('products_variants')->where('product_id', $product->id)->where('variant_name', 'XS')->update(array('variant_specs' => Input::get('xsmall_size'), 'price_change' => Input::get('xsmall_price'), 'total_stock' => Input::get('xsmall_stock'), 'stock_used' => 0));
```

When you call this:

```
$product->fill($input)->save();
```

It also saves 'dirty' (modified) models that also belong to it, which can include `products_variants` relationships. From the sound of it, you are incorrectly applying changes directly through SQL, and then the model's save method is overwriting it.

You seem unclear about what your code is actually doing, and I would strongly suggest simplifying it down and adding in code as you begin to understand what each line does. I think your question is the byproduct of copying an example and adding your own work without understanding how Laravel handles relationships and models. There is almost never a good reason to use raw SQL or DB statements.

Comment: thank you , but i has to fix some probelm by EOD . i will defiantly start as per your suggestions.

Comment: I want one more help , how can i initiate chat with you please